# RevenueCat requires Xcode 13.2 with Swift 5.5.2 to compile

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, xcode, revenuecat

I’m using **revenueCat** plugin in my flutter project.

when building my flutter app in Xcode it throw this exception:

[image: from xcode]

**Exception message**

RevenueCat requires Xcode 13.2 with Swift 5.5.2 to compile.

**flutter doctor:**

```
Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.9, on macOS 12.6.3 21G419 darwin-x64, locale
    en-US)
Checking Android licenses is taking an unexpectedly long time...[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version
    32.1.0-rc1)
    ! Some Android licenses not accepted. To resolve this, run: flutter doctor
      --android-licenses
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.2)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.71.2)
```

**installed Xcode version:**

Version 14.2 (14C18)

**swift --version:**

swift-driver version:1.62.15 Apple Swift version 5.7.2 (swiftlang-5.7.2.135.5 clang-1400.0.29.51)

Target: x86_64-apple-macosx12.0

How to build the app successfully?

Answer (score 0):

In the pod File, the swift version was specific, so I remove it and it worked fine.